# Not Sure What This Symbol Means

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, notation, observables

In the equation below is a notation that I can't figure out what it means. I tried looking up [math symbols](https://www.rapidtables.com/math/symbols/Basic_Math_Symbols.html) but couldn't find anything there that fit this. This also happens to be a hard thing to look up. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

$$\langle X\rangle = \langle Y\rangle = \langle Z\rangle = 0.$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xdSTZYc8uRg. You can look up more videos/articles online if it still does not make sense.

Comment: Please do not post formulae as screenshots, but use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/479421) instead.

Comment: (this time there's a good reason to post a screenshot, but avoid it in the future)

Comment: @NíckolasAlves Thanks for the information, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of quantum mechanics, if a system is in a state $|\psi \rangle$ and $X$ is an operator (for example, the position operator), then

$\langle X \rangle = \langle \psi | X | \psi \rangle$

is the expectation value of the operator in that state.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it was Bra-Ket but hadn't seen it used without the pipes.

Comment: @Hercislife Note that $\langle X\rangle$ is not bra-ket notation - it is a notation common to many fields of physics and mathematics which typically denotes some type of average. The right-hand side of the expression, on the other hand, *does* utilize bra-ket notation.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as [Angle-bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Angle_brackets) notation.

They are used in group theory, statistical mechanics.

In line with the tags for quantum computing: It is used in quantum mechanics (i.e. it's a physics symbol). It denotes the quantum state of a particle. Known as [bra-ket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation) notation where it would always be seen with a vertical bar in between.

Comment: I thought it was Bra-Ket notation but hadn't had the professor use it without the pipes before. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. Please feel free to upvote or award the accepted tick as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

> In the below screenshot is a notation that I can't figure out what it means. I tried looking up [math symbols][1] but couldn't find anything there that fit this. This also happens to be a hard thing to look up. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

> $<X>=<Y>=<Z>=0$

The $<\ldots>$ notation means you are taking an average.

For example, in single-particle quantum mechanics $<X>=<\psi|\hat X|\psi>$ is the average value of $x$ over the probability density $|\psi(x, y, z)|^2$.

But, in general, $<X>$ could indicate any averaging procedure:
$$
<X> = \int dx dy dz P(x, y, z)x\;,
$$
where $P(x, y, z)$ is any non-negative function that integrates to 1: $\int dx dy dz P(x, y, z) = 1 $.

In the context of single-particle quantum mechanics the average value of $x$ you are most likely interested in is:
$$
<X> = \int d^3r |\psi(x, y, z)|^2x
$$